# Doing something while receiving data from serial port in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, serial-port

I want to create program, that will color ellipse in any way depending on the received data in "real time". The data is like: `x1-1`, `x2-1` etc.

I have strange problem, I can see while debugging that, color of filling ellipse should change, but it doesn't happen.

Part of my code with receiving data:

```
 private void ReceiveData()
            {
                SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600);
                serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                serialPort.Open();
            }

 private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                object sender,
                SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
                string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
                if (indata.Contains(" "))
                {
                    testString = indata.Substring(0, 4);

                }
                Console.Write(indata);
            }
```

I can see received data in console, even after click on button, that starts receiving data. The `testString` is to extract single `x1-1` from `indata`, that is still growing during receiving data. I know that it doesn't work like it should but it doesn't matter now.

Code of action on button:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReceiveData();
            while (true)
            {
                if (testString == "x1-1") x1.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
                else x1.Fill = Brushes.Red;
            }
        }
```

`x1` is ellipse that I want to make red or blue. I can set the breakpoint in this function and I can see that it should change. I think the problem is, that program is waiting for close port and finish transmission, and then maybe it would change, but I need to have it in "real time". Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Show us `Console.Write(testString);`

Comment: First iteration is empty but then it looks normally, like `x1-1`, `x2-1`

Comment: And if you put a breakpoint on your 'if' statement, does teststring ever equal "x1-1'? If so, your UI thread is never getting a chance to redraw because you're doing a `while(true)`... you're hammering the CPU. Prove it to yourself -- open up task manager and see if a core spikes at 100%. Consider updating the UI on a timer that executes every 300-500ms. It'll give the UI thread a chance to do its work.

Comment: sometimes `x1-1`, sometimes `x2-1`. The buffer with data is like `x1-1 x1-1 x1-1 x1-1 x2-1` etc. There is no other options.

Comment: Yeah.. never use a while(true) loop on the UI thread. You're hanging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are going about this the wrong way. Instead of constantly checking the value of `teststring` you need to just start the comm port listener and let it run in the background - as this will be on it's own thread. Then you need to create a Data Binding to the color. Whenever the comm port listener parses a string, it can automatically update the color.

First, in the CommPort class:

```
class MyCommPort : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    SerialPort serialPort = null;
    public MyCommPort()
    {
        serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
        serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        serialPort.Open();
    }
    ~MyCommPort()
    {
        serialPort.Close();
    }

    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string testString = null;
        string indata = sp.ReadLine();
        if (indata.Length >= 4)
        {
            testString = indata.Substring(0, 4);
            // Update the value
            if (testString == "x1-1") EllipseBrush = Brushes.Blue;
            else EllipseBrush = Brushes.Red;
        }
        Console.Write(testString);
    }

    // Create a property that will be bound
    private SolidColorBrush ellipseBrush = Brushes.Red;
    public SolidColorBrush EllipseBrush
    {
        get { return ellipseBrush; }
        set
        {
            ellipseBrush = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EllipseBrush");
        }
    }

    // Extend the INotifyPropertyChanged interface
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            // Alert anyone bound to this that the value has changed
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, set the Ellipse's DataContext to the CommPort class and bind the Ellipse's Fill property to EllipseBrush.
Now all you have to do is start the Commport listener (`ReceiveData();`) and the color updates should happen automatically.

For example: MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="delete_me.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Fill="{Binding Path=EllipseBrush}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind: MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ellipse.DataContext = new MyCommPort();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is problem with this part of code:
            `if (testString == "x1-1") EllipseBrush = Brushes.Blue;
            else EllipseBrush = Brushes.Red;`
because EllipseBrush can't be use in this place in this static context

Comment: You can remove `static` from the function. I have updated the answer. Also, I just wrote a test app and this works.

Comment: It's good to know. Well, so thanks. I will try to do it tommorow, I have to find information how to make what you wrote below the code, because it's not so obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hang the UI thread by having a `while(true)` inside of a button click event. Use a DispatchTimer to do work every 500s instead.

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer MyTimer = null;
private void ReceiveData()
{
    MyTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    MyTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);
    MyTimer.Tick += MyTimer_Tick;
    MyTimer.Start();
    SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600);
    serialPort.DataReceived += new 
             SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
    serialPort.Open();
}

private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                object sender,
                SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    if (indata.Contains(" "))
    {
        testString = indata.Substring(0, 4);

    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReceiveData();
}

private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (testString == "x1-1")
    {
       x1.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
    }
    else 
    {
       x1.Fill = Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is difference between `EllipseBrush = Brushes.Blue;` and `x1.Fill = Brushes.Blue`? With `EllipseBrush = Brushes.Blue;` it can't be compile becouse missing declaration, with `x1.Fill = Brushes.Blue` it's still doesn't work.

Comment: But it still doesn't work. The bug has to be in other place.

Comment: I've edited the code in the Timer_Tick event. If you update it to what I have, and you breakpoint the code, and step into it, what do you see happen?

Comment: Program can't stop there. It seems like it has never been used.

Comment: Sounds like you were making edits while the program was running?

Comment: No, I meant, that breakpoint in if statement in `MyTimer_Tick event` is not reachable.

Comment: I'm so sorry... I never had you start the timer.

Comment: I added a line to start the timer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hehe, I'm sure it would make a problem but with that line it's still the same situation. Program can't stop in `MyTimer_Tick` function :(

Comment: You're saying that you never see the breakpoint hit at all, when you put the breakpoint on the 'if' statement, right?

Comment: When the program is running, is the breakpoint a solid red dot, or an outline of a red circle?

Comment: It's a solid red dot, I put it on if, and on else.

Comment: I used the wrong Timespan constructor. Change it to (0,0,0,0,500) (just add one extra 0).

Comment: It would have eventually executed... after 500 seconds! :( Once again...sorry. Answer edited.

Comment: Yay, it works now. I am grateful for the help. You don't have to apologize :) I'm glad it works :) :)

Comment: Wonderful -- for what it's worth, you should look into using the MVVM pattern with DataBinding. It makes WPF so much cleaner :)

Comment: This a very poor design. The SerialPort class is event driven but you are using a timer to poll it. That doesn't make any sense. Think of it like this: your friend is coming over. Do you a) check the front door every 5 seconds to see if someone is there? Or b) go do other things and only go to the door when the bell rings?

Comment: @johnny I assume you've not experienced needing to debounce a device before. You claim poor design, but if we are going to use your analogy, then consider this: your friends are ringing the doorbell incessantly. You can a) get nothing done because you are answering the door constantly or b) only check periodically.

Comment: I have lots of experience with serial ports and have never needed to debounce any incoming data. Also, OP mentions no need for this. If a flood of repeated messages is an issue, you can still use an event-driven design. A simple check like `if (currentMsg == this.lastMsg) return;` in the event handler will discard repeated messages.

Comment: Your check fails for cases where multiple message types exist, and data is being streamed rapidly with frequent variations. Also, I do not see the OP mentioning "no need for this".

Comment: The check can easily be expanded for different messages....Without more info about the speed and type of incoming data, we can only agree to disagree. There are cases where polling the port may be desired, but using `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` callback doesn't make sense in that scenario.